# No Table Three Column Category Layout

Tags: php, html

I am working with some code and am hung up a bit on a certain piece. Hoping to find some help. I am using the open source WeBid Auction Script, and trying to eliminate some of the tables used in the layout. The following function is the code in question.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    // redirect to global categories list
    header ('location: browse.php?id=0');
    exit;
}
else
{
    // Retrieve the translated category name
    $par_id = $category['parent_id'];
    $TPL_categories_string = '';
    $crumbs = $catscontrol->get_bread_crumbs($category['left_id'], $category['right_id']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($crumbs); $i++)
    {
        if ($crumbs[$i]['cat_id'] > 0)
        {
            if ($i > 0)
            {
                $TPL_categories_string .= ' &gt; ';
            }
            $TPL_categories_string .= '<a href="' . $system->SETTINGS['siteurl'] . 'browse.php?id=' . $crumbs[$i]['cat_id'] . '">' . $category_names[$crumbs[$i]['cat_id']] . '</a>';
        }
    }

    // get list of subcategories of this category
    $subcat_count = 0;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $DBPrefix . "categories WHERE parent_id = " . $id . " ORDER BY cat_name";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $system->check_mysql($result, $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
    $need_to_continue = 1;
    $cycle = 1;

    $TPL_main_value = '';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        ++$subcat_count;

        if ($cycle == 1)
        {
            $TPL_main_value .= '<tr align="left">' . "\n";

        }
        $sub_counter = $row['sub_counter'];
        $cat_counter = $row['counter'];
        if ($sub_counter != 0)
        {
            $count_string = ' (' . $sub_counter . ')';
        }
        else
        {
            if ($cat_counter != 0)
            {
                $count_string = ' (' . $cat_counter . ')';
            }
            else
            {
                $count_string = '';
            }
        }
        if ($row['cat_colour'] != '')
        {
            $BG = 'bgcolor=' . $row['cat_colour'];
        }
        else
        {
            $BG = '';
        }
        // Retrieve the translated category name
        $row['cat_name'] = $category_names[$row['cat_id']];
        $catimage = (!empty($row['cat_image'])) ? '<img src="' . $row['cat_image'] . '" border=0>' : '';
        $TPL_main_value .= "\t" . '<td ' . $BG . ' width="33%">' . $catimage . '<a href="' . $system->SETTINGS['siteurl'] . 'browse.php?id=' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . $row['cat_name'] . $count_string . '</a></td>' . "\n";

        ++$cycle;
        if ($cycle == 4)
        {

            $cycle = 1;
            $TPL_main_value .= '</tr>' . "\n";
        }
    }

    if ($cycle >= 2 && $cycle <= 3)
    {
        while ($cycle < 4)
        {
            $TPL_main_value .= '    <td width="33%">&nbsp;</td>' . "\n";
            ++$cycle;

        }
        $TPL_main_value .= '</tr>' . "\n";
    }
```

Instead of parsing into a table, I want it to go into the content areas of the html below:

```
    <div class="colmask blogstyle4">
       <div class="colmid">
            <div class="colleft">
            <div class="col1">
                <!-- Column 1 start -->
                <!-- Content -->
                <!-- Column 1 end -->
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
                <!-- Column 2 start -->
                <!-- Content -->
                <!-- Column 2 end -->
            </div>
            <div class="col3">
                <!-- Column 3 start -->
                <!-- Content -->
                <!-- Column 3 end -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried a few things, but my code just repeats itself.
Here is one of the ways I tried:

```
    // get list of subcategories of this category
    $subcat_count = 0;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $DBPrefix . "categories WHERE parent_id = " . $id . " ORDER BY cat_name";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $system->check_mysql($result, $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
    $need_to_continue = 1;
    $cycle = 1;
    $column = 1;

    $TPL_main_value = '';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        ++$subcat_count;

        if ($cycle == 1)
        {
            $TPL_main_value .= '<div class="col'.$column.'">' . "\n";

        }
        $sub_counter = $row['sub_counter'];
        $cat_counter = $row['counter'];
        if ($sub_counter != 0)
        {
            $count_string = ' (' . $sub_counter . ')';
        }
        else
        {
            if ($cat_counter != 0)
            {
                $count_string = ' (' . $cat_counter . ')';
            }
            else
            {
                $count_string = '';
            }
        }
        if ($row['cat_colour'] != '')
        {
            $BG = 'bgcolor=' . $row['cat_colour'];
        }
        else
        {
            $BG = '';
        }
        // Retrieve the translated category name
        $row['cat_name'] = $category_names[$row['cat_id']];
        $catimage = (!empty($row['cat_image'])) ? '<img src="' . $row['cat_image'] . '" border=0>' : '';
        $TPL_main_value .= "\t" . '<p>' . $catimage . '<a href="' . $system->SETTINGS['siteurl'] . 'browse.php?id=' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . $row['cat_name'] . $count_string . '</a></p>' . "\n";

        ++$cycle;
        if ($cycle == 4)
        {

            $cycle = 1;
            $TPL_main_value .= '</dv>' . "\n";
    ++$column;
        }
    }

    if ($cycle >= 2 && $cycle <= 3)
    {

        while ($cycle < 4)
        {
            $TPL_main_value .= '    <p>&nbsp;</p>' . "\n";
            ++$cycle;


        }
        $TPL_main_value .= '</div>
' . "\n";

    }
```

and I got:

```
<div class="col1">
    <p><a href="/browse.php?id=2">Art &amp; Antiques</a></p>
    <p><a href="/browse.php?id=198">Automotive (1)</a></p>
    <p><a href="/browse.php?id=29">Books</a></p>
</dv>
<div class="col2">
    <p><a href="/browse.php?id=68">Clothing &amp; Accessories</a></p>
    <p><a href="/browse.php?id=72">Coins &amp; Stamps</a></p>
    <p><a href="/browse.php?id=75">Collectibles</a></p>
</dv>
<div class="col3">
    <p><a href="/browse.php?id=113">Comics, Cards &amp; Science Fiction</a></p>
    <p><a href="/browse.php?id=122">Computers &amp; Software</a></p>
    <p><a href="/browse.php?id=127">Electronics &amp; Photography</a></p>
</dv>
<div class="col4">
    <p><a href="/browse.php?id=133">Home &amp; Garden</a></p>
    <p><a href="/browse.php?id=143">Movies &amp; Video</a></p>
    <p><a href="/browse.php?id=150">Music</a></p>
</dv>
<div class="col5">
    <p><a href="/browse.php?id=157">Office &amp; Business</a></p>
    <p><a href="/browse.php?id=162">Other Goods &amp; Services</a></p>
    <p><a href="/browse.php?id=170">Sports &amp; Recreation</a></p>
</dv>
<div class="col6">
    <p><a href="/browse.php?id=174">Toys &amp; Games</a></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

which is not going to work and is not what I am after.
Could someone help me to understand the changes I need to make to accomplish parsing into the 3 columns instead of the table it uses currently?

Comment: So why not use a table? If you are presenting tabular data, a table oftentimes is the most logical choice to do that.

Comment: @Mike Brant Because I don't want to use tables....

Comment: Don't fall for the tables are evil line of thinking.  I would agree that using tables for entire pages layouts as typically done 5-10 years ago is bad, but using tables to present tabular data should not be frowned upon at all. It is in fact the preferred way to do things by most experienced web developers.  the problem you face in not using tables (or a table-like structure as pointed out in the answer from vladkras below), is that you then need to take your row-based database results and concert to a column-based data structure - requiring to put the whole thing in memory.

Comment: Not that they are evil, they just don't work with the rest of the layout I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think there's no reason to avoid tables, but maybe this short example will make you a step closer. Common table looks like thi s. Lets change all tags to divs leaving corresponding classes.

```
<table>                            <div class="table">
    <tr>                               <div class="tr">
        <td>One</td>                       <div class="td">One</div>
        <td>Two</td>                       <div class="td">Two</div>
        <td>Three</td>                     <div class="td">Three</div>
    </tr>                  ==>         </div> 
    <tr>                               <div class="tr">
        <td>1</td>                         <div class="td">1</div>
        <td>2</td>                         <div class="td">2</div>
        <td>3</td>                         <div class="td">3</div>
    </tr>                              </div>
</table>                           </div>
```

Now the only thing we have to do is to convert them using css's property `display`

```
.table { display: table; }
.tr { display: table-row; }
.td { display: table-cell; }
```

That's it. If you add a little bit more properties, it will look exactly the same:
`border-spacing: 2px;` for table-div and `padding: 1px;` for cell-divs

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/jE7e4/)**

If you want your example to look like:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| .col1 | .col2 | .col3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| .col4 | .col5 | .col6 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

you have to wrap every three divs with additional div

```
$TPL_main_value = '<div class="row">';
// instead of $TPL_main_value = '';
// then close it and open again every three loops
if ($i%3==0) $TPL_main_value = '</div><div class="row">';
// and don't forget to close it after while loop ends
```

maybe [this code](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/130-isy) will help you

Comment: Thanks for the visualization. Not what I was thinking. I added some details showing the results of my test.

Comment: @mobilestimulus what do you mean `they`?

Comment: They meaning the six columns. I want to change the php so I have three columns, not six with extra divs to deal with...

Comment: @mobilestimulus check [this](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/130-isy) and my answer again

Comment: Let me ask this. What part of the php is saying to only put in 3 <p>s per DIV and then start again? If I can change the math, then the thing should work as I want, right?

Comment: `if ($cycle == 4)
        {

            $cycle = 1;
            $TPL_main_value .= '</dv>' . "\n";
    ++$column;
        }` does it, you can change this number (4), but you have to change it in all other places

Comment: That sounds like it might be the answer to get the code to do what I want, which is divide the results into only 3 columns. So what would the final code look like?