# How To Change Numbers Based On Results

Tags: php

I have a follow up question on something I got help with here the other day ([No Table Three Column Category Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586027/no-table-three-column-category-layout)).
The script is as follows:

```
$res = mysql_query($query);
$system->check_mysql($res, $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
$parent_node = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$id = (isset($parent_node['cat_id'])) ? $parent_node['cat_id'] : $id;
$catalist = '';
if ($parent_node['left_id'] != 1)
{
    $children = $catscontrol->get_children_list($parent_node['left_id'], $parent_node['right_id']);
    $childarray = array($id);
    foreach ($children as $k => $v)
    {
        $childarray[] = $v['cat_id'];
    }
    $catalist = '(';
    $catalist .= implode(',', $childarray);
    $catalist .= ')';
    $all_items = false;
}

$NOW = time();

/*
specified category number
look into table - and if we don't have such category - redirect to full list
*/
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $DBPrefix . "categories WHERE cat_id = " . $id;
$result = mysql_query($query);
$system->check_mysql($result, $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
$category = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    // redirect to global categories list
    header ('location: browse.php?id=0');
    exit;
}
else
{
    // Retrieve the translated category name
    $par_id = $category['parent_id'];
    $TPL_categories_string = '';
    $crumbs = $catscontrol->get_bread_crumbs($category['left_id'], $category['right_id']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($crumbs); $i++)
    {
        if ($crumbs[$i]['cat_id'] > 0)
        {
            if ($i > 0)
            {
                $TPL_categories_string .= ' &gt; ';
            }
            $TPL_categories_string .= '<a href="' . $system->SETTINGS['siteurl'] . 'browse.php?id=' . $crumbs[$i]['cat_id'] . '">' . $category_names[$crumbs[$i]['cat_id']] . '</a>';
        }
    }

    // get list of subcategories of this category
    $subcat_count = 0;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $DBPrefix . "categories WHERE parent_id = " . $id . " ORDER BY cat_name";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $system->check_mysql($result, $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
    $need_to_continue = 1;
    $cycle = 1;
    $column = 1;

    $TPL_main_value = '';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        ++$subcat_count;

        if ($cycle == 1)
        {
            $TPL_main_value .= '<div class="col'.$column.'"><ul>' . "\n";

        }
        $sub_counter = $row['sub_counter'];
        $cat_counter = $row['counter'];
        if ($sub_counter != 0)
        {
            $count_string = ' (' . $sub_counter . ')';
        }
        else
        {
            if ($cat_counter != 0)
            {
                $count_string = ' (' . $cat_counter . ')';
            }
            else
            {
                $count_string = '';
            }
        }
        if ($row['cat_colour'] != '')
        {
            $BG = 'bgcolor=' . $row['cat_colour'];
        }
        else
        {
            $BG = '';
        }

        // Retrieve the translated category name
        $row['cat_name'] = $category_names[$row['cat_id']];
        $catimage = (!empty($row['cat_image'])) ? '<img src="' . $row['cat_image'] . '" border=0>' : '';
        $TPL_main_value .= "\t" . '<li>' . $catimage . '<a href="' . $system->SETTINGS['siteurl'] . 'browse.php?id=' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . $row['cat_name'] . $count_string . '</a></li>' . "\n";

        ++$cycle;
        if ($cycle == 7)   // <---- here
        {

            $cycle = 1;
            $TPL_main_value .= '</ul></div>' . "\n";
    ++$column;
        }
    }

    if ($cycle >= 2 && $cycle <= 6)   // <----  here  minus 1
    {

        while ($cycle < 7)  //  <---- and here
        {
            $TPL_main_value .= '    <p>&nbsp;</p>' . "\n";
            ++$cycle;


        }
        $TPL_main_value .= '</ul></div>'.$number.'
' . "\n";

    }
```

I was needing to divide the resulting links into three columns to fit my html layout.
We accomplished this by changing the numbers in the code marked with "// <---- here".
Because the amount of links returned could be different each time, I am trying to figure out how to change those numbers on the fly. I tried using

```
$number_a = mysql_num_rows($result);
$number_b = $number_a / 3;
$number_b = ceil($number_b);
$number_c = $number_b - 1;
```

and then replacing the numbers with `$number_b` or `$number_c` but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Ever heard of modulo?

Comment: Not until now. How can I use it?

Comment: check this http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php for modulo.

Comment: @Naeem Can you help me to understand how and where to use this?

Comment: or @Ares maybe you can...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before, you can use the [mod (`%`) function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php) to do that.

Basically what it does is to get the remainder after division. So, if you say `11 % 3`, you will get `2` since that is the remainder after division. You can then make use of this to check when a number is divisible by 3 (the remainder will be zero), and insert an end `</div>` in your code.

Here is a simplified example on how to use it to insert a newline after every 3 columns:

```
$cycle = 1;
$arr = range (1, 20);
$len = sizeof ($arr);

for ( ; $cycle <= $len; $cycle++)
{
    echo "{$arr[$cycle - 1]}     ";

    if ($cycle % 3 == 0)
    {
        echo "\n";
    }
}

echo "\n\n";
```